# Clock Changing Speed in a Different Place

Tags: everyday-life, time

I had a clock in my kitchen for a while, and it ran a bit slowly. The clock in my other room, ran slowly as well, but eventually it broke and I moved the clock in the kitchen to where the other clock was. After I moved it, it started to run too quickly. I'm not very good with physics or science, but does anybody know why this happened (or happens)?

Comment: This would be a question for a clock maker rather than a physicist. It would probably be welcome in the [engineering SE](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/) though.

Comment: I think your clock(s) are just whacky and no profound laws of physics are coming into play. Unless, is your kitchen traveling close to the speed of light? =)

Comment: @heather tsk, tsk.....would it make any difference in the OP frame of reference? As you say, the clock are wacky. My office clock always runs slow, or maybe I just want 5pm to hurry up.

Comment: @count_to_10, just as all school clocks seem to run slow. Of course, I was joking about the OP's kitchen moving at relativistic speeds.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way of finding the reason for such "co-incidences."  It is quite likely the two events are unconnected : why should one clock running fast be connected with another running slow?  Just because they both measure time does not mean there is a connection.

The scientific response is to do an experiment or investigation. Open the clocks up to see if anything is going wrong; test the batteries.  If you are serious, get hold of some identical clocks and test them in both places to see if there is a real, consistent effect.

The same effect (clocks slowing down or speeding up) could have several causes - batteries running low, increase in room temperature, somebody altered the time by mistake while cleaning the clock, change in humidity, mechanical failure of a minor component, etc.

Comment: I don't think this should be an answer...a comment would probably suffice.

Comment: @heather: It is more than a comment. I have suggested some possible causes and solutions.  So I have addressed the question.  Perhaps I need to emphasise the physics in my answer?  Throw a few equations around? Apply SR? Or define a wave function?  ... The question is probably off-topic anyway.

Comment: Fair point. I think there are three things that bugged me about it. 1. It isn't really an *answer*, though it is a suggestion of how to find it (which I don't think is right, but that's beside the point). 2. It isn't really explaining a physics concept. 3. Arguably, you shouldn't give an answer to an off-topic question.

Comment: @heather : 1. It attempts to explain what is going on, so to that extent it's and answer.  2. True.  3. Mea culpa!

Comment: fair enough about the first point. I don't think it really matters in the end though - the question will probably get put on hold. (I probably shouldn't have even brought it up. Oh well.)

Comment: You have helped someone out, and given generally physics based answers, (and that's what the everyday life tag is for. ) Works for me as an answer, to a reasonable question.